# jQuery Ajax failing to call to MVC 3 Controller method on Windows XP

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Hi i am invoking a Ajax call to my controller method from a view on button click. Ajax method fails by giving the error "Object not Found". This happens when it is deployed on Windows XP. It does not happen on Windows 7. I am stuck up on this issue from Two days with no help. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is my code.

DisplayAttributes.cshtml

```
function DisplayFullImage() 
{
    var model = {
        ChoosenColor: sendDesignerData,
        TotalDensity: TotalPixelFilled
    };

    var urls = '@Url.Action("GetColors","Designer")';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urls,
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function (data) { },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (Response, Status, Error) { alert("Response: " + Response + " Status: " + Status + " Error: "+Error); }
    })
}

function Generate()
{
  //Some code to fill sendDesignerData and TotalPixelFilled
  DisplayFullImage();
}
```

DesignerController.cs

```
public class DesignerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Designer/

    public ActionResult DisplayAttributes()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void GetColors(DesignColors DsgColor)
    {
        if (DsgColor.ChoosenColor != null && DsgColor.TotalDensity > 0)
        {
            Session["Colors"] = DsgColor;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Colors> DummyColors = new List<Colors>();
            DsgColor.ChoosenColor = DummyColors;
            DsgColor.TotalDensity = 0;
            Session["Colors"] = DsgColor;
        }

    }

}
```

On button click Generate() method is called and i fill an Json object "sendDesignerData" with some values and also assign numeric value to "TotalPixelFilled" variable and then call DisplayFullImage()

The application work when deployed on Windows 7 and does not work on Windows XP. The Ajax call fails and i get error "Object Not Found" in alert.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: whats the error code and responsetext?

Comment: What browser? Do you get the same error in Firefox, Chrome, et al?

Comment: @Nitin The error code is HTTP 404 error and Response text is object not found. I verified Url.Action methods URL. It seems to be correct too.

Comment: @Tieson, I use FireFox V 26.0. I get the error over there. We do not support other browsers.

Comment: Windows XP runs IIS 6 which requires additional steps to get MVC running as opposed to IIS 7 which will support it out of the box (pretty much).  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/ will give you some guidance on IIS 6 changes you could potentially make.

Comment: @Tommy, I have gone through the link which you have provided. I have taken care of all those points. But i use IIS 5.1 on my windows XP. Will go through deployment of MVC3 on IIS 5.1.

Comment: You're correct, its is IIS 5.1, my mistake.  The instructions should still work the same however, let us know how it goes.